# The ban on the processing of the second request

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I use Node.JS + Socket.IO. The problem is this: the user can simultaneously send two requests to the server. The second request must be rejected if the first had not yet processed. How to implement it? 
I'm now doing user.disabled = true if the user sends a request and user.disabled = false 50 MS. But this does not fix the bug, if the first request takes longer than 50 MS. 
There is an option to write user.disabled = false everywhere, where it ends the request, but because of asynchrony Node.JS it will have to write in so many places, which greatly pollutes the code. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: How about disable two request on frontEnd? Like disable send button or rejecting all others clicks until response is back to user?

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk

In a pinch you could, but this option also has disadvantages: 
1) Not always the server in response to a press of a button sends the answer - sometimes it's not necessary. 
2) the Server can send some response before we process the request.
3) the Server may send information that is not related to the first query, and the frontend determines that it is already possible to send new requests.
4) a Small vulnerability to hackers: with frontend-and they can remove the protection.